# C# How to run a process as a host?

Tags: c#, process

I want to run a program that will be a host for another one, so the main program would be launched, which would then launch for example another executable and the main program would be the main process running it?

To summarize:

- Launch.exe
- Actualprogram.exe

Launch.exe executes (hosting) running Actualprogram.exe, so only Launch.exe would be listed as a process. Thanks

Comment: You can host plugins in your executable and run their code through some custom interface, but this requires some rules for plugin implementation. Do you really need to host any child processes?

Comment: Hey! I do indeed need to do so and I need to be running the executable, not that as a plugin, so maybe pack it somehow, just not sure how that works yet.

Comment: You could use ``Process.Start(...)`` or ``Assembly.Load(...)`` in order to dynamically load another executable from your main ``Launch.exe``.